# SP returned result set - SQL Server - Java

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I thought that a given Stored Procedure returns to the calling code (e.g. to `JDBC`/`Hibernate`) only the result set from the last `SELECT` executed. But it seems it returns more than one result set if there's more than one `SELECT` present/executed in the body of the SP, and what's worse: it seems `JDBC`/`Hibernate` detects the first result set as the actual result.

Was my understanding incorrect? Could anyone clarify how this works? Citing  some authoritative references is (as usual) desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server will return ALL result sets from the execution of a stored procedure, not just the last one.

If a SP has more than a single result set returned, they will be returned in order and all will be returned, barring any errors.

E.G.:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MultipleResults
AS
BEGIN
SELECT 'Result #1'
SELECT 'Result #2'
SELECT 'Result #3'
END
```

The above will return 3 result sets, each with a single row.
[See example N.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332(v=SQL.110).aspx)

Personally, I am not a fan of this as most tools don't understand that multiple can be returned and do not properly work with it. I try to keep a single result set (if any) to be returned per SP.

Comment: Thanks. So basically my understanding/impression was incorrect, wasn't it?

Comment: It was, but it's not widely known that multiple result sets can be returned without using MARS (Multiple Active Result Sets) from a connection setting point of view. It's a huge pain to return more than a single result set per SP.

Comment: You may be able to overload the JDBC/nHibernate consuming methods for that SP to correctly return data (or edit the SP). I'm not very familiar with Java and nHibernate - but most ORMs let their methods be overloaded.

Comment: But ... I noticed that if a SP has `select top 1 @some_var = some_col from some_table; ` and then a 2nd "normal select", then the result of that 1st select is not counted (I mean it is not returned as a result set to the calling code). Why so?

Comment: Ah, yes. Because in this example, no result set is being returned - merely a variable (@Some_Var) is being SET through a select statement. There is nothing to return (the results of the select are just setting a variable).

Comment: Look at the "Caution" box and the paragraphs underneath it: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953(v=SQL.105).aspx

Comment: http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/88/posts/10104/variable-assignment-using-set-and-select-in-sql-server.aspx